Azure Private Endpoint with Terraform - smart way to do mapping between Subresource and Private DNS Zone
Let me start with saying that I'm an absolute Terraform and IaC in general newbie, so whatever it described here might not be the best approach to things. Doing a lot of stuff based on different Terraform codes we have already in the organization, without doing much trainings/courses/etc. so a lot of self-learn approach is used.
What I'm attempting to do is create a generic Terraform module that I could use across different other modules within Azure. This is what I currently have:
data "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "dnszone" {
  provider            = azurerm.csvc
  name                = var.pdns_name
  resource_group_name = var.pdns_rg_name
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint" {
  for_each            = [var.subresource_names_map]
  name                = format("%s-%s-%s", "pe", var.private_connection_resource_name, each.value)
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.pe_resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = var.private_endpoint_subnet_id

  tags = merge({ StartDate = formatdate("DD-MM-YYYY", time_static.time.rfc3339) }, var.env_tags)

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = format("%s-%s-%s", var.private_connection_resource_name, each.value, "Conn")
    private_connection_resource_id = var.private_connection_resource_id
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = [each.value]
  }

  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = var.pdns_rg_name
    private_dns_zone_ids = [data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.dnszone.id]
  }
}

And I believe this is generally going to work for two scenarios:

Resources that do have a 1 subresource per 1 DNS zone (good example could be Key Vault that have 1 subresource - vault going into a single private DNS zone privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net)
Resources that do have more than 1 subresource going into 1 DNS zone, ex. Synapse Analytics have two subresources - Sql and SqlOnDemand that go into     privatelink.sql.azuresynapse.net, since I could do a simple

pdns_name = "privatelink.sql.azuresynapse.net"
subresourece_names_map = ["Sql", "SqlOnDemand"]

What I'm thinking of doing is is solving a third scenario - one resource can have multiple subresources go into multiple private DNS zone (ex. Storage Account having overall 5 different subresources going into 5 different PDNSZ).
This would require having some sort of dictionary that would map subresources into different PDNSZ, however I think there are cases where a single subresource can be mapped into different PDNSZ (I think both Synapse and PostgreSQL use Sql as subresource, few resources use portal etc.).
Right now I could achieve this by simply referencing PE module more than once and this is probably the safest, but not sure whether it's the most optimal code wise.
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "time_static" "time" {}
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                          = var.name
  location                      = var.location
  resource_group_name           = var.resource_group_name
  sku_name                      = var.sku_name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption   = true
  tenant_id                     = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days    = var.soft_delete_retention_days
  purge_protection_enabled      = true
  enable_rbac_authorization     = var.enable_rbac_authorization
  public_network_access_enabled = var.public_network_access_enabled

  tags = merge({ StartDate = formatdate("DD-MM-YYYY", time_static.time.rfc3339) }, var.env_tags)

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [tags]
  }
}

module "private_endpoint" {
  source       = "../private_endpoint"
  pdns_rg_name = var.pdns_rg_name
  pdns_name    = var.pdns_name

  pe_resource_group_name           = var.pe_resource_group_name
  location                         = var.location
  private_endpoint_subnet_id       = var.private_endpoint_subnet_id
  private_connection_resource_id   = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  private_connection_resource_name = azurerm_key_vault.kv.name
  subresource_names_map            = var.subresource_names_map

  env_tags = var.env_tags
}


Use a map of lists for pdns_zone_map to handle multiple subresources and DNS zones efficiently. Here's a simplified structure for your Terraform module:
hcl
Copy code
variable "pdns_zone_map" {
type = map(list(string))
}
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint" {
for_each = var.pdns_zone_map
Private endpoint resource configuration
}
@glaeran


Azure Private Endpoint with Terraform - smart way to do mapping between Subresource and Private DNS Zone

We need to make 3 main changes in the code configuration i.e., the way we map the resources by use of for_loop over this map and we also need to make changes according to code shared as mentioned below in the module private_dns_zone_group .
configuration:
module/private_end_point/main.tf:
 resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "dnszones" {
      for_each = { for dns in flatten([for dns in values(var.subresource_dns_map) : dns]) : dns => { name = dns, rg_name = var.pdns_rg_name } }
    
      name                = each.value.name
      resource_group_name = each.value.rg_name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint" {
      for_each            = var.subresource_dns_map
      name                = format("%s-%s-%s", "pe", var.private_connection_resource_name, each.key)
      location            = var.location
      resource_group_name = var.pe_resource_group_name
      subnet_id           = var.private_endpoint_subnet_id
    
      tags = merge({ StartDate = formatdate("DD-MM-YYYY", timestamp()) }, var.env_tags)
    
      private_service_connection {
        name                           = format("%s-%s-%s", var.private_connection_resource_name, each.key, "Conn")
        private_connection_resource_id = var.private_connection_resource_id
        is_manual_connection           = false
        subresource_names              = [each.key]
      }
    
      dynamic "private_dns_zone_group" {
        for_each = [for dns_zone in each.value : {
          name = dns_zone
          id   = azurerm_private_dns_zone.dnszones[dns_zone].id
        }]
    
        content {
          name                 = private_dns_zone_group.value.name
          private_dns_zone_ids = [private_dns_zone_group.value.id]
        }
      }
    }

main.tf:
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example_rg" {
      name     = var.pdns_rg_name
      location = var.location
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example_vnet" {
      name                = "vksb-vnet"
      address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "example_subnet" {
      name                 = "vksb-subnet"
      resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.name
      virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example_vnet.name
      address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example_storage" {
      name                     = "vksbstorageacct"
      resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.name
      location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.location
      account_tier             = "Standard"
      account_replication_type = "LRS"
    }
    
    module "private_endpoint_example" {
      source = "./modules/private_endpoint"
    
      pdns_rg_name                    = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.name
      pe_resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.name
      location                        = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.location
      private_endpoint_subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.example_subnet.id
      private_connection_resource_id  = azurerm_storage_account.example_storage.id
      private_connection_resource_name = azurerm_storage_account.example_storage.name
      subresource_dns_map = {
        "blob"       = ["privatelink.blob.core.windows.net"]
        "file"       = ["privatelink.file.core.windows.net"]
      }
    
      env_tags = {
        Environment = "dev"
        Project     = "example"
      }
}

deployment:



For more Info related to DNS zones provision using terraform you can refer to answer provided by me in SO link.
Refer:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_endpoint
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_dns_zone
Azure Private Endpoint & DNS zones using Terraform | by Kirupakarans | Medium by kirupakarans
